# csv.writerow now working after adding for-loop?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I'm writing tweet status data into a csv file if it matches certain keywords. The csvwrite works well when I have this initial on_status code:

```
    def on_status(self, status):

        # Creating this formatting so when exported to csv the tweet stays on one line
        tweet_text = "'" + status.text.replace('\n', ' ') + "'"
        # Filter for keyword, only write csv if correct keyword(s) found
        csvw.writerow([status.id,
                        status.user.screen_name,
                        status.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%y'),
                        status.user.followers_count,
                        tweet_text])
        return True
```

However, when I add in a for loop with the filterKeyword, the csvwrite does not fill up. The csv-file remains totally empty with no values. It does, however print out the "Found tweet by keyword: + word"  and the "after csvw" parts. Cannot for the life of me debug this properly..

```
    def on_status(self, status):

        # Creating this formatting so when exported to csv the tweet stays on one line
        tweet_text = "'" + status.text.replace('\n', ' ') + "'"
        # Filter for keyword, only write csv if correct keyword(s) found
        for word in filterKeywords:
            if word in tweet_text:
                print("Found tweet by keyword: " + word)
                csvw.writerow([status.id,
                               status.user.screen_name,
                               status.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%y'),
                               status.user.followers_count,
                               tweet_text])
                print("after csvw")
        return True
```

Any help much appriciated!

Comment: Define "the csvwrite does not work". What happens?

Comment: The csv-file remains empty, is not filled with any values at all.

Comment: It is as if thecsv.writerow is not called upon at all.

Comment: As a sanity check, put `print(id(csvw.writerow))` in main when it's declared, and again before you call it in `on_status()` just to see if they are the same object ID.

Comment: Good point, now that I checked they are different id's - how come?

Since it is working in the first case, the object ID changes somehow when I add the for & if loops.. How is that possible? How to fix? -Are hard questions

Comment: Still unknown how to fix this

Comment: Is it the same object ID in the first case without the for and if loops? Maybe it's fallen out of scope some how. Try adding a `global csvw` as the first line in `on_status()`, or you could pass the csvw when you instantiate the class that contains `on_status()` and store it as `self.csvw` in the class init.

Comment: Can you `print(filterKeywords, tweet_text)` ?  I also suggest you ensure all words in `filterKeywords` are lowercase and you use `if word in tweet_text.lower():`

Comment: The object ID is also different in the first case without the for and if loops, actually..

`print(filterKeywords, tweet_text)` works fine. I will use the lowercase - good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: kamion, how do you mean I add a `global csvw`, by defining csvw in every on_status call or?

What blows my mind is that in works in the first simple case but not in the if/for loop.

Comment: kamion, thank you I defined the global csvw at the start of on_status and it works. Great! How do I give you internet points?`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `csvw` is out of scope from where you instantiated it in main, so try adding `global csvw` declaration in your function:

```
    def on_status(self, status):
        # add this line
        global csvw

        ...
```